# J2ME NoClassDefFoundError com.sun.midp.io.properties

Tags: java-me

My J2ME application use the class : com/sun/midp/io/Properties

when i try to install it on nokia C3 or samsung

I see this error in my phone:
No Class Def Found Error
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
com/sun/midp/io/Properties

Example code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
int s = p.size();
```

But it works fine with LG

How can I solve this issue. 
I tried to add the jsr which contain the class to my application but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes provided by Sun are subject to license terms, that's probably why they are not presented on all mobile platforms. Also the JVM classes and components vary from platform to platform, since they cover different device configurations and features. You can't solve this issue.

Comment: thanks, So I have to rewrite my application without using this class to fit other devices. and how can I know which classes are present in my device.